# how do I deal with error 1004 in vba excel?

Tags: excel, vba

Basically I have 3 worksheets . From the first worksheet  I get a value (rotid) , and by using the match function  I try to find the value in the second worksheet , and copy the row associated with the value into worksheet 3 where  y is the index of the row in sheet 2 which corresponds to the value  (rotid). But sometimes a value is not found in worksheet 2 and the program crashes . How can I deal with this error ?

worksheet 1 is  list,
worksheet 2 is rotmain2,
worksheet 3 is imdb

btw this is how my code looks like . Im not sure how to use codetags.

```
Sub combine_imdb_rot_data()

' y is the index of the row in rotmain2 which corresponds to rotid

Dim y As Variant

Sheets("imdbmain").Select

For i = 1 To 4415

  ' select sheet list and assign rotid for value of the cell in row i+1  and column 7
  rotid = Sheets("list").Cells(i + 1, 7).Value

  ' if rotid is not empty,
  If Len(rotid) > 0 Then

    'look for a row that corresponds to the rotid in worksheet "rotmain2"
    Sheets("rotmain2").Select
    'x = Sheets("list").Cells(i + 1, 7).Row
    y = WorksheetFunction.Match(rotid, Range("B1:B4218"), 0)

    If IsNumeric(y) Then                             
        ' copy the information in the row             
        Range(Cells(y, 1), Cells(y, 13)).Select
        Selection.Copy                   
        ' paste it into row i+1 in worksheet "imdbmain"
         Sheets("imdbmain").Select
         'select row i+1 in imdbmain
        Range(Cells(i + 1, 9), Cells(i + 1, 21)).Select
        Workbooks(1).Sheets(1).Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Else
        ' copy the information in the row                  
        Range(A4220, M4220).Select
        Selection.Copy

        ' paste it into row i+1 in worksheet "imdbmain"
         Sheets("imdbmain").Select
         'select row i+1 in imdbmain
        Range(Cells(i + 1, 9), Cells(i + 1, 21)).Select
        Workbooks(1).Sheets(1).Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If   
End If
Next
End Sub
```

I also tried with another method suggested by Remou.
Is this how the .find method works ? Im not sure but when I use it I get a Runtime error  13 type mismatch:

```
Sub combine_imdb_rot_data()

    ' y is the index of the row in rotmain2 which corresponds to rotid

    Dim y As Variant

  Sheets("imdbmain").Select

  For i = 1 To 4415

    ' select sheet list and assign rotid for value of the cell in row i+1  and column 7
    rotid = Sheets("list").Cells(i + 1, 7).Value

    ' if rotid is not empty,
    If Len(rotid) > 0 Then

        'look for a row that corresponds to the rotid in worksheet "rotmain2"
        Sheets("rotmain2").Select
        'x = Sheets("list").Cells(i + 1, 7).Row
        Set y = Range("B1:B4218").Find(rotid)


        If y Is Nothing Then

            ' copy the information in the row
            'Range("1:4," & x & ":" & x).Copy
            'Range("A&x"&:&"M&x").Copy
            'Copy empty row

            Range("A101:M101").Select
            Selection.Copy


            ' paste it into row i+1 in worksheet "imdbmain"
             Sheets("imdbmain").Select
             'select row i+1 in imdbmain
            Range(Cells(i + 1, 9), Cells(i + 1, 21)).Select
            Workbooks(1).Sheets(1).Paste


        Else

            ' copy the information in the row
            'Range("1:4," & x & ":" & x).Copy
            'Range("A&x"&:&"M&x").Copy

            Range(Cells(y, 1), Cells(y, 13)).Select
            Selection.Copy


            ' paste it into row i+1 in worksheet "imdbmain"
             Sheets("imdbmain").Select
             'select row i+1 in imdbmain
            Range(Cells(i + 1, 9), Cells(i + 1, 21)).Select
            Workbooks(1).Sheets(1).Paste
            Application.CutCopyMode = False




        End If

  End If
  Next


End Sub
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for details on how to format the code.

Answer (score 1):

You could trap the error, or perhaps use Find:

```
rotid=5 ''Let us say

With Worksheets(1).Range("B1:B4218")
    ''Find returns a range object, so we use Set
    Set y = .Find(rotid, LookIn:=xlValues, lookAt:=xlWhole)
    If y Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "Not found"
    Else
        ''This will print a cell, $b$15, for example
        Debug.Print y.Address
        ''This will print 5
        Debug.Print y.Value
    End If
End With
```

Futher information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa195730%28office.11%29.aspx

Comment: Hi Remou , Im still abit unfamiliar with VBA . Could you explain to me what the statement  Set y = Range("B1:B4218").Find(rotid) mean ? I remember there is an excel function FIND(find_text,within_text,start_num) , but it can only find the position of a string  within a text not a cell. Is it related to that function?

Comment: I have added some notes and a link to MSDN. I hope this is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you may want to do is put `On Error Resume Next` at the top of your module. Give that a try first.

Comment: Please tell me this was tongue-in-cheek.

Comment: How can I implement it ? 
The idea is that I would like to copy an empty row from worksheet 2 to worksheet 3 , if the error occurs which means that a  value cannot be found using match function  and run the programm regularly if there is no error (which means match returns a numeric value)

Comment: Quite serious, this is how you handle a non-MATCH (which returns an "#N/A" if no match is found - error 1004). Put this - On Error Resume Next - in your code, right below the Sub line. Don't get me wrong here, this may not be the most optimized way of doing what excel34 is asking for, but it quickly handles the error. If the code is still not working after that, then there are other problems to look at.